# Incorporating a join with a subquery into an existing query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that contains records for sports teams game stats and records, and I'm currently having an issue with figuring out how to retrieve the total points against a team over the season and incorporating it into a query that returns their total wins and losses.

The current query I have that does not show their points against is:

```
SELECT league_team_data.`Team Name` AS TeamName, league_team_data.TeamID, games.Result, count(*) AS Total, sum(case when games.`Result` = 'WIN' then 1 else 0 end) GamesWon, sum(case when games.`Result` = 'LOSS' then 1 else 0 end) GamesLost, sum(case when games.`Result` = 'WIN' then 2 when games.`Result` = 'TIE' then 1 else 0 end) Points, SUM(Score) PointsFor 
                FROM league_team_data

                LEFT JOIN games
                ON games.TeamID = league_team_data.TeamID

                INNER JOIN teams_in_divisions
                ON teams_in_divisions.DivisionID_FK = 2 AND games.TeamID = teams_in_divisions.TeamID_FK

                GROUP BY TeamID 
                ORDER BY PointsFor DESC, Points DESC
```

The '2' hard coded here is staying hardcoded as it works for it's purpose.

The query that returns their total points against is:

```
SELECT SUM(Score) FROM `games` WHERE TeamID <> 1 AND 
GameID IN (SELECT GameID FROM games WHERE TeamID = 1)
```

The '1' hardcoded here needs to be changed to work with the league_team_data.TeamID from the above query.

So, I need to incorporate the second query into the first, in order to add a column for 'Points Against', which is what the second query returns.

The 'games' table has this data (and more, but this is what is pertinent for this question):

```
GameID | TeamID | Score |
   1       3        20
   1       5        28
```

Each row is the game stats from a game for one of the teams involved in the game, so the 'Score' column is that teams score. So, in order to get the points against the team I need to sum the 'Score' column for all rows with a GameID that they played in, but not the score from their row but rather their opponents row.  The second query accomplishes this.

Sorry if this is a really basic question (I feel like I'm missing something obvious!), but any help would be very much appreciated!

As requested, here are the create table statements:

Table league_team_data:

```
CREATE TABLE `league_team_data` (
`TeamID` mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Team Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Team Name Short` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Team Name Initials` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`Team Background Image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`Team Logo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`TeamID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table games:

```
CREATE TABLE `games` (
`Game Date` date NOT NULL,
`GameTime` time NOT NULL,
`GameID` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
`TeamID` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
`Team` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`Score` int(5) NOT NULL,
`Result` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`Home Team` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`HomeTeamID` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
`Away Team` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`AwayTeamID` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
`Game Status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`SeasonID` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`GameID`,`TeamID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_gameid` FOREIGN KEY (`GameID`) REFERENCES `league_games` (`GameID`) ON  DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table teams_in_divisions:

```
CREATE TABLE `teams_in_divisions` (
`DivisionID_FK` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
`TeamID_FK` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `DivisionID_TeamID` (`DivisionID_FK`,`TeamID_FK`),
KEY `TeamID_FK` (`TeamID_FK`),
CONSTRAINT `teams_in_divisions_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`TeamID_FK`) REFERENCES `league_team_data` (`TeamID`),
CONSTRAINT `teams_in_divisions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`DivisionID_FK`) REFERENCES `league_divisions` (`DivisionID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please provide some samples along with the `CREATE TABLE` Statements...

Comment: @Benni Do you want the create table for the 'games' table or all of the tables?  I'm not sure what you want for samples, but I'd be happy to provide anything that would help if you can clarify what you mean.

Comment: @JonEvans You're allowed to edit your question! BTW, isn't it more usual to store the result (i.e. score) of the fixture, rather than who won, etc.?

Comment: Thanks. Please provide CREAT-Statements for all tables used as well as some Test-data (INSERT-Statements).

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the tip!  I store both the score and who won or lost as separate columns, though I could just derive this from the score.  The reason why the information is divided into 2 separate rows per GameID is that each team stores their game stats here (like total yards, penalties, etc) which I need to keep separate.

Comment: @Benni I actually just figured out the answer as I was getting the create statements for you, so I'll just add that as an answer, but thanks so much for getting me thinking properly about the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a simple way to do what I was trying to do, though I'm not sure how optimized this sort of query is.

I simply needed to add the subquery directly into the original SELECT statement.  Here's the final code:

```
SELECT league_team_data.`Team Name` AS TeamName, 
league_team_data.TeamID, games.Result, count(*) AS Total, 
sum(case when games.`Result` = 'WIN' then 1 else 0 end) GamesWon, 
sum(case when games.`Result` = 'LOSS' then 1 else 0 end) GamesLost, 
sum(case when games.`Result` = 'WIN' then 2 when games.`Result` = 'TIE' then 1 else 0 end) Points, 
SUM(Score) PointsFor, 
(SELECT SUM(Score) AS PointsAgainst FROM `games` WHERE TeamID <> league_team_data.TeamID AND GameID IN (SELECT GameID FROM games WHERE TeamID = league_team_data.TeamID)) AS PointsAgainst

FROM league_team_data 

LEFT JOIN games ON games.TeamID = league_team_data.TeamID 

INNER JOIN teams_in_divisions ON teams_in_divisions.DivisionID_FK = 1 AND games.TeamID = teams_in_divisions.TeamID_FK 

GROUP BY TeamID ORDER BY Points DESC
```

The part I added was the "SELECT SUM(Score) AS PointsAgainst..." line.

Again, this could be horribly inefficient, but it does work!

Comment: As it stands, this answer is only useful for you, because no one else understands your schema (unless they read through the comments above - unlikely)

Comment: @Strawberry Should I add all of my CREATE TABLE code for all the tables?  I'd like it to be useful for everyone.

That being said, I think the simple ability to add another SELECT query inside of an existing SELECT query the way that I did was all I really needed to know, and if someone else had a similar problem wouldn't that solve it?

Comment: It's up to you. If it was me, that's what I would do.